# when using super().method, which methods is called in this situation

Tags: java

Suppose you have an object of type BlahChild that is an extension of BlahParent, what happens when BlahChild calls super().someMethod and someMethod contains a call to another function, anotherMethod() that is also overriden in BlahChild?

Does BlahChild's anotherMethod get called, or BlahParent's anotherMethod?

Comment: You should add code snippets for such questions

Comment: do you mean `super.someMethod()` ?  `super()` is only allowed as the first command inside a constructor body (Explicit Constructor Invocation) and does not return anything.

Comment: Why don't you just write a small program to try it out yourself? Experimenting is a great way to learn how things work.

Comment: because I am more interested in the underlying reasons rather than the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-static methods are always [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) in java, so **yes**.

From wikipedia:

> ***In Java, all non-static methods are by default "virtual functions."** Only methods marked with the keyword final, which cannot be overridden, along with private methods, which are not inherited, are non-virtual.*

It will call the `BlahChilds` implementation.

### Example:

```
class Parent {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Parent: method");
    someOtherMethod();
    }
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Parent: some other");
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Child: method");
        super.method();
    }

    @Override
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Child: some other");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child().method();
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Child: method
Parent: method
Child: some other   // <-- Child.someOtherMethod gets called, from Parent.method
```

Comment: I hate it when people call classes `Child` and `Parent` because biological inheritance is a totally different concept from object oriented programming inheritance. In bio inheritance, there is no **is a** relationship between child and parent.

Comment: Thanks aioobe, I will look into java and virtual methods.

Answer (score 3):

You should really post concrete code for such questions.

However, from your description it sounds like `anotherMethod()` is virtual (i.e. not final), and the object is a `BlahChild`, so the overridden version in `BlahChild` is supposed to be called.

Why don't you test it yourself btw?

Answer (score 2):

The overridden method in the child class will be called.

> super().someMethod

That won't even compile. You probably mean `super.someMethod()`, and perhaps what got you confused is the idea that `super` returns something like a "hidden superclass instance" on which the method is then called. There is no such thing. A method call is basically a message to an object saying "please execute the piece of code with this name", and the object then looks at its class to see what piece of code that is. `super` is merely a way to make the object look at its superclass instead, which is conceptually unclean but often very useful because many overriding methods need the functionality of the method they override (and do something extra before and/or after).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was thinking (some magical superclass instance). So basically, the object calls the parent's method, but when that method has a call to another method, that other method is still taken within the context of the object rather than the parent class, just like any other method call would. That makes sense for sure...

Answer (score 0):

i hacked tgether the following example and since the methods are virtual calling the super method calls the method in the child class:

check [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-1997/jw-06-hood.html) for an explanation

so that running the example yields:

```
child: test1 // call to child.test1()
child: test2 // child test2() gets called

super: test1 // call to super.test1()
child: test2 // child.test1 gets called
```

example code:

```
package de.congrace.doodles;

public class ChildClass extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("child: test1");
        test2();
    }
    @Override
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("child: test2");
    }

    private void callSuperTest() {
        super.test1();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildClass c=new ChildClass();
        c.test1();
        c.callSuperTest();
    }
}



package de.congrace.doodles;

public class SuperClass {
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("super: test1");
        test2();
    }
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("super: test2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that article is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks!